# Gdal Ogr2Ogr Split polygon shapefile by line shapefile

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, splitting

I have two shapefiles, a polygon shapefile (lake) and a line shapefile (boudary) I want to create a new shapefile containing the polygon splitted by the polyline using ogr2ogr.

[image: oginal shapes]

[image: Result]
how can i do this?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by 'Split'? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: i edited the post think you

Answer (score 3):

If we have GDAL OGR with Spatialite support and liblwgeom (e.g. OSGeo4W):

```
ogr2ogr splitted_lake.shp lake.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Split(g1.geometry,g2.geometry) AS geometry FROM lake AS g1, 'boundary.shp'.'boundary' AS g2" -explodecollections
```